# Raspbian Jessie ROS INDIGO download image

Tags: rviz, moveit, rasbperrypi, rqt, jessie

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

during christmas vacation I compiled ROS INDIGO on a Raspbian Jessie image with the following features / packages installed:

C-BERRY TFT framebuffer driver 
ROS INDIGO

- ROS base
- RQT
- imageview
- geometry
- moveit
- rviz
- robot model

Here is the link for downloading:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzu4fg52rneFX1V3REhKTmM2VWc&authuser=0

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200504/raspbian-jessie-ros-indigo-download-image/) by [MartinHummel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4385/martinhummel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2015-01-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Waterfox](https://answers.ros.org/users/20829/waterfox/) on 2015-02-15**:
Thanks for the image. I'm using this very successfully to run my RPi powered rover

**Comment by [devtron](https://answers.ros.org/users/21673/devtron/) on 2015-02-21**:
Dude you are an absolute lifesaver with this.

**Comment by [LukeH](https://answers.ros.org/users/25639/lukeh/) on 2016-01-18**:
File was corrupted when I extracted it with 7-zip.  Any advice?  I can try to gunzip it instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Martin, this isn't the appropriate way to advertise a contribution such as this, if you would like to use ros answers for this then you should ask a question and answer it yourself, for example see: http://answers.ros.org/question/122266/how-can-i-fix-unable-to-handle-index-format-version-2-please-update-rosdistro/

---

On another note, any time you are distributing a binary, you need to provide details like how you created the image and how someone else could reproduce it. While I'm certain that your intentions are pure, without some sort of signing it would be very easy for someone to advertise such an image which intentionally or unintentionally contains malicious software. By providing a way for others to reproduce it, you can get independent validation and build trust in your image.

More importantly, while a binary image is certainly useful, it would be good to have instructions on how to do this so that others can build on what you've done and improve the solution that way. It is very hard for someone to reproduce and iterate on a binary image. I would recommend you just detail the steps you used to create the image on a wiki page, similar to something like the UDOO instructions: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UDOO

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the image has saved me a lot of time getting ROS up and running on my Pi.

I can confirm that the image does not boot in RPi2 but does on B+

---

Originally posted by [Stephen Eaton](https://answers.ros.org/users/22220/stephen-eaton/) with karma: 11 on 2015-04-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1